# Launch TortoiseSVN command for more multiple paths simultaneously

Tags: command-line, tortoise-svn

### Situation

I have a development project with the following repository structure:

```
root/
 + core/
      + branches/
      + tags/
      + trunk/
 + module/
      + branches/
      + tags/
      + trunk/
```

How can I commit `core/trunk/` and `module/trunk/` together in one TortoiseSVN commit dialog?

### Limiting Factors / Notice

- Unfortunately -- don't ask ;) -- the working copy is not sparse i.e. `branches/`, `tags/` have been checked out completely. They require quite a while to scan, if launching a TortoiseSVN operation from the context menu of `root/`.
- Although I favour atomic commits, commits sometimes require (in my opinion) a cross-directory commit.
- I want to launch it from e.g. a batch file (Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type/select `myCommit.cmd`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

### First steps

I already found out from [StackOverflow: How to automate a commit in TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8015936/828080) that TortoiseSVN might be called like that:

`TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"A:\path\to\root"`

- multiple `/path:`arguments are not accepted by [TortoiseProc](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics)

### tl;dr

(How) can I pass multiple paths to `TortoiseProc.exe  /command:abcd /path:"more\paths"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StackOverflow: how to pass parameters to tortoiseproc.exe via file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694423/how-to-pass-parameters-to-tortoiseproc-exe-via-file) indicates that paths can be passed as `*`-separated list:

`TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"A:\path\to\root\core\trunk*A:\path\to\root\module\trunk"`

Comment: Also documented at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html as: `Since some of the commands can take a list of target paths (e.g. committing several specific files) the /path parameter can take several paths, separated by a * character. `

Comment: @ssnobody Oops, I have not spotted that on reading the documentation. (But maybe `*` just looks to much like a globbing wildcard when dealing with paths, doesn't it?)